# Why is my script is only getting the first row of my php table? below is my code

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

This is my JavaScript code

```
$('input#name-submit').on('click', function() {
    var name = $('input#name-submit').val();
    if($.trim(name) != ''){
        $.post('getmodalreasonUT.php', {name: name}, function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    }
});
```

and this is my php code

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['Pending'])){
    echo "<header class='panel-heading'> Undertime Pending</header>";
    echo "<table class='table table-bordered'>
    <thead>
    <tr class='tbl-record'>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name of Employee</th>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>Date Filed</th>
    <th>Number of hours</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>";

    $sql =   "SELECT * FROM utrequestform WHERE user_eid = '$employeenumber' and check_managerandsspv = '0'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){                             
            echo "<tr class='tbl-info text-center'>                            
            <td>".$row['user_eid']."</td>
            <td>".$row['nameofemployee']." </td>
            <td>".$row['position']."</td>
            <td>".$row['datefiled']."</td>
            <td>".$row['noofhours']."</td>    
            <td><input type='submit' id='name-submit' value='$row[id]'></td>
            </tr> ";

        }
    }else{
        echo "<tr><td colspan='10'>No pending UT request.</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</tbody></table>";
}
?>
```

This is my echo php code.

```
<?php 
    include ('connection.php');
    $please = $_POST['name'];
    echo $please;
?>
```

[image: this is my database structure]

Comment: could you show us your database structure !!

Comment: how to upload image?

Comment: you have an image icon in the bar tools click on it and browse your image .

Comment: This is my echo php code.
<?php 
 include ('connection.php');

 $please = $_POST['name'];

 echo $please;

 ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are generating the HTML like this:

```
<input type='submit' id='name-submit' value='$row[id]'>
```

Which will render the same input several times with the same ID. This is invalid markup. You need to change that line for:

```
<input type='submit' id='name-submit-$row[id]' name='request-val' value='$row[id]'>
```

Then change your jQuery for:

```
$('input[name="request-val"]').on('click', function() {
    var name = $(this).val();
    if($.trim(name) != ''){
        $.post('getmodalreasonUT.php', {name: name}, function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    }
});
```

**Avoid having duplicated IDs at all costs**. That will save you from a lot of frustration later down the road.

Comment: Sir Danny, Im getting 4 results. But everytime I click the button only the first row value is selected.

Comment: And what do you expect to be posted when you click the button? an array with all the values?

Comment: I need to get the id of the selected row.

Comment: ill try your answer sir wait.